# Runtime variables passed through to packaged installers?

Tags: parameters, nsis

I've got an NSIS script that checks the platform it's running on and launches an appropriate MSI. This works great, but it means that I can't use parameters like `/SILENT` on my bundled installers.

Is there any way to get the whole parameter string and pass it on the the msi installers?

Here's my code at the moment:

```
Section
Initpluginsdir
${If} ${RunningX64}
  File "/oname=$pluginsdir\inst.msi" "${DIR}\64bit.msi"
${Else}
  File "/oname=$pluginsdir\inst.msi" "${DIR}\32bit.msi"
${EndIf}
ExecWait '"msiexec" /i "$pluginsdir\inst.msi"'
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
!include "FileFunc.nsh"
...
${GetParameters} $0
ExecWait '"msiexec" /i "$pluginsdir\inst.msi" $0'
```